# Stacked boxplot and scatter plot - group BOTH by same variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, scatter

I am trying to create a scatter plot stacked on a boxplot. Similar dummy data below. The boxplot behaves well, as I want one boxplot for each of the three "exp" variables both "before" AND "after" (as seen in graph below, 6 box plots).

The problem however is that I also want the scatter plot data to lie on top of the correct plot (divided by before/after). Now, the points are just in between the two box plots, as you can see.

```
exp <- rep(c("smile", "neutral", "depressor"), each=5, times=2)
time <- rep(c("before", "after"), each = 15)
result <- rnorm(15, mean=50, sd=4)
result <- append(result, c(rnorm(15, mean=47, sd=3)))
data <- data.frame(exp, time, result)

ggplot(data, aes(exp, result, fill=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point()
```

I would really appreciate some input, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solving your issue?
Here you add the time group in `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(exp, result, fill=time)) +
  stat_boxplot(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(1)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(1), outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(fill = time, group = time), color="black", 
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .1, dodge.width = 1))
```

## Before

[image]

## After

[image]

Comment: `jitter.width=0` from `position_jitterdodge` `geom_point` function if you want dots fully alligned but it makes lecture hard

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. One question: do you need both stat_boxplot() and geom_boxplot()? Is there a reason to use both?

Comment: You are completely right, you can leave out stat_boxplot(). It is used to upgrade your boxplots, for example error bars. In the above code, it adds no required info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `geom_jitter` like this:

```r
exp <- rep(c("smile", "neutral", "depressor"), each=5, times=2)
time <- rep(c("before", "after"), each = 15)
result <- rnorm(15, mean=50, sd=4)
result <- append(result, c(rnorm(15, mean=47, sd=3)))
data <- data.frame(exp, time, result)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(exp, result, fill=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I was perhaps a bit unclear but this actually does not group the "correct" points on top of the correct boxplot, as you can see here: 

`ggplot(data, aes(exp, result, fill=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=time))`